# Android - Use a custom view class in my activity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, view, android-custom-view

I'm very new to Android development and trying to implement my own custom view which will allow me to use draw operations on a canvas. My custom view should draw a rectangle onto the screen in the onDraw() function, however it doesn't seem to work, no rectangle is drawn.

The very basic main activity that I'm trying to use the custom view with:

```
package com.example.testcanvas;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


  }

}
```

XML files for the activity, which I have tried to add the custom view to:

fragment main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testcanvas.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >




</RelativeLayout>
```

activity main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.testcanvas.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<com.example.testcanvas.CustomView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/custom_view" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

and finally, my custom view class:

```
package com.example.testcanvas;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

public CustomView (Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
    int dCenter = 40;     //Distance from center in px, NOT in dp
    int centerX = (int)(getWidth()/2);
    int centerY = (int)(getHeight()/2);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);  //The square will draw in the color blue now


    Rect rect = new Rect(centerX-dCenter, centerY-dCenter, centerX+dCenter, centerY+dCenter);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    setWillNotDraw(false);   //Allows us to use invalidate() to call onDraw()
    postInvalidate();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {}

}
```

Could anybody possibly point out where I've gone wrong? Thanks.

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); activity_main doesnt have your custom view in it fragment main.xml does

Comment: Hi JRowan thanks for your help, I moved the custom view into activity main, however now the screen I see is split into two, the half top black and bottom white, still no blue rectangle drawn, any advice?

Comment: im actually not to sure i never extended surfaceview but ill go into my eclipse and give it a shot, see whats up and get back to you

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think the view is working now after your advice, however the onDraw function doesn't seem to be working still.

Comment: Fixed! Added getHolder().addCallback(this); to the constructors of CustomView

Comment: nice dont forget to post your answer and check it